# How to wrap selection in quotes using PhpStorm?

Tags: php, configuration, phpstorm

I have two different machines both using PhpStorm. One has the feature enabled, that I can select a `text` and by pressing <kbd>'</kbd> it will become `'text'`:

[image: Example of the working feature]

Yet the other one will just erase the text:

[image: Example of the not working feature]

I have forgotten how I set it up. Where can I enable this feature?

Comment: +0.5 for the question and +0.5 for the nice pictures - free after: an image may tell more than a thousand words!

Comment: @bish If you are running a Gnu/Linux distribution, I suggest looking into [byanz](http://askubuntu.com/a/123515/32792)

Comment: Thanks for the info but I don't need those image creator (therefore I'm a windows guy). I wanted to make clear that in my opinion this is a beautiful example to show that images **may** improve a question a lot, knowing that images in SO question are often not wanted (for proper reasions) - but here it's different.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

The option is hiding under:

Editor > General > Smart Keys: Surround selection on typing quote or brace

[image: Screenshot of the PhpStorm config to enable the feautre]

Comment: @DarekKay And there is an explicit button when posting a question to answer my own question. It saves me the time to setup a blog and I can use this question as a reference if I ever want to enable this feature again.

Comment: @DarekKay This is encouraged behaviour: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: Found in the same location in WebStorm preferences.

Comment: stupid question, is there also something similar to replace selected text with regex?
For example, I select a text 'my.email@gmail.com' and now I want to automatically replace with a mailto link: '<a href="mailto:my.email@gmail.com">my.email@gmail.com</a>'. Like a macro or a programmable short key?